# synchronous generator speed

Tags: synchronous-motor

Isn't a synchronous generator speed fixed at synchronous speed regardless of the load?
In the question the synchronous generator has different speed why?

[image]

Reference: Electrical Machines, Drives, and Power Systems

Pearson Education Limited 2014, by Theodore Wildi

Answer (score 3):

The two prime movers have variable speed under load. The generators do not appear to be connected to a grid, which will fix their speed.

The two synchronous generators will each have a frequency proportional to their prime mover's speed. That constant of proportionality changes with their number of poles, which is why the prime movers have a ratio of their speed ranges of approximately 2:1.

The two generators are in parallel, so their frequencies will be identical, so they will force the prime movers to maintain an exactly 2:1 speed ratio.

Your job is presumably to work out how the load will be split between the two prime movers, and what their final speed and frequency will be.

It would be reasonable to make an assumption that the power being produced by each prime mover is linearly related to its speed in the no-load to full-load region. Note that the prime movers don't have the same slope to the speed/power line, nor do they have a 2:1 speed ratio at no load, or at full load.